# Shopify Script Tag: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-app

Currently working on a shopify app which uses script tags to add a section on the thank you page (order status page).

This is my test-script.js file:

```
console.log('this is coming from script tag api!')

const header = $('div.section__content').parent('.section');
 
var myContent = function($) {

//content box contains some basic styling with divs and an image which I haven't included
const contentBox = $( ....).css(....)

header.prepend(contentbox)
}
```

I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function when I check the chrome console. Am I supposed to add a jQuery script? Am confused on the next steps.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, have you added the library to the page?

Comment: If more info is required please let me know

Comment: I'm not using jQuery

Comment: It sure looks like you are. What is `$(...)` if its not jQuery?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'll go through that question now

Comment: yes it is sorry! - do I need to include some jQuery script in my file then?

Comment: Yes. Please do include it.

Comment: would it be something like: header.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js";

Comment: No. jQuery needs to be loaded and run before this script does. Otherwise it will fail at `$(...` like before

Comment: Also, sometimes these CMS's protect the `$` function, in which case you might use `jQuery` instead, like `jQuery('div.section__content')...`